# Using AppBarTheme causes default text size?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to acheive transparent appbars everywhere in my app using AppBarTheme in my MaterialApp's theme. But it's causing the text size to be the default of 14.0 instead of title size.

I guess it's something to do with TextStyle inheritance, but I don't know much about that.

Example code:

```
class ExampleScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ThemeData theme = ThemeData();
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: theme.copyWith(
        appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
          color: Colors.transparent,
          brightness: Brightness.light,
          elevation: 0,
          //I want the defaults, which is why I'm copying an 'empty' ThemeData
          //perhaps there's a better way to do this?
          textTheme: theme.textTheme,
          iconTheme: theme.iconTheme,
        ),
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('AppBar!'),
        ),
        body: Text('Some text'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: did you find a solution for this ?

Comment: Looks like it's a bug related to this: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/38716
Go give it a +1 react if it affects you too!

Answer (score 6):

This can be achieved by specifying the **textTheme** inside of the *AppBarTheme*.

Indeed, the *AppBarTheme()* has a fully customisable parameter which takes a **TextTheme**. You almost had it in your question.

Try:

```
  class ExampleScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ThemeData theme = ThemeData();
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: theme.copyWith(
        appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
          color: Colors.transparent,
          brightness: Brightness.light,
          elevation: 0,
          //I want the defaults, which is why I'm copying an 'empty' ThemeData
          //perhaps there's a better way to do this?
          textTheme: theme.textTheme.copyWith(
            title: theme.textTheme.title.copyWith(fontSize: 20.0),
          ),
          iconTheme: theme.iconTheme,
        ),
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('AppBar!'),
        ),
        body: Text('Some text'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The **textTheme** has a *title* parameter inside of which you can set the **fontSize**. The default **fontSize** for titles is 20.0.

Notice the lines:

```
textTheme: theme.textTheme.copyWith(
                title: theme.textTheme.title.copyWith(fontSize: 20.0),
              ),
```

You can read more about the [TextTheme class here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextTheme-class.html)

Each of the parameters is customisable which shows the power of Flutter.

Comment: Thanks, this is a good workaround but I was trying to avoid explicity setting the font since if I change the title size later, I don't want to set it in two places

Comment: how to define the title text theme in main.dart file for entire the app? Please suggest. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Used the workaround from https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/38716

```
class ExampleScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ThemeData theme = ThemeData();
    var localizedTheme = ThemeData.localize(theme, theme.typography.geometryThemeFor(ScriptCategory.englishLike));
    theme = theme.copyWith(
      appBarTheme: theme.appBarTheme.copyWith(
        color: Colors.transparent,
        brightness: Brightness.light,
        elevation: 0,
        textTheme: localizedTheme.textTheme,
      ),
    );
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: theme,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('AppBar!'),
        ),
        body: Text('Some text'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: how to define the title text theme in main.dart file for entire the app? Please suggest. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Theme.of(context)` like this:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return MaterialApp(
    theme: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
      appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
        color: Colors.transparent,
        brightness: Brightness.light,
        elevation: 0,
        textTheme: Theme.of(context).textTheme,
        iconTheme: Theme.of(context).iconTheme,
      ),
    ),
    home: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('AppBar!'),
      ),
      body: Text('Some text'),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: how to define the title text theme in main.dart file for entire the app? Please suggest. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution. MaterialApp->builder function.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MaterialApp/builder.html

```dart
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        builder: (context, widget) {
          var baseTheme = Theme.of(context);
          return Theme(
              data: baseTheme.copyWith(
                appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(color: Colors.transparent),
              ),
              child: widget);
        },
        home: HomeView());
  }
```